# Android: How to get calling app's name when my app is invoked with a DeepLink

Tags: android, android-deep-link, install-referrer

I need to get the app name that invoked my activity. For api<=32 I am able to get this using getReferrer() method in the OnCreate() of my activity. But this returns null in Api 33. Is there any other reliable way to get the calling app's name?

I also tried getCallingPackage () and getCallingActivity() but these two return the current package name.